# If $f(z)$ and its conjugate are both holomorphic on a region $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ then $f(z)$ is constant on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't understand why this would be true.  Why would this be false for functions that are not constant like $f(z) = z$?  How could this be proven?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f,\bar f$ are holomorphic. Then so is $\Re f$. What do you know about holomorphic functions which only take real values? Do the same with $\Im f$.

Comment: if the output is real it would have to have to be a real number?